# Component with folders and sub-folders

Tags: reactjs

Can somebody help me with the creation of the component that would support creation of folders at any level? So, for example, first level contains several folders, then each of the folders contains subfolders, then each of the subfolders contains subfolders, then each of the subfolders contains subfolders and so on and so fort. And on side, I should have 'Add' button, so I can select folder and click on that button to create new folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about a router? For example, do you want the ability to bind a component to a certain URL such that when you go to, say, `localhost:3000/signin` a sign in component is displayed? If so, I suggest you look at some like React Router. It'd be great if you could clarify your question. Also, I suggest you mention that it's specifically about React.js in the title and add some code samples/examples of what you have in mind.

Comment: No, I have a task where I should create a possibility for the user that he can create folders and his personal notes inside those folder. And I am stuck with the folder creation, I don't have idea how to create a possibility so that the user can create folders, subfolders inside those folders, subfolders inside that folders,

Comment: @Boris Okay, so you want to make a functionality allowing a user to create a folder structure. That has very little to do with React. You need to create a server with that functionality and expose it with a REST API endpoint. For that, the best option is probably Express.js. After that, you need to call that API endpoint within your frontend with `fetch()` to run that functionality.

Comment: Instead of leaving suggestions in your answer about how the questioner should form their question I prefer you do that in the comments section of the question.

This will make your answer easier to read and more on topic for those looking for an answer to the same question.